# 24v brushless DC Driver Pinout

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, pinout, 24v

I have some Brushless DC Motors with drivers and I need some help finding the pinout of the drivers.

Please take a moment to view the pictures here, clicking on a picture will show its higher-resolution version **in the current** tab.

Driver Top:

[image]

Driver Back:
[image]

Motor:

[image]
<sub>(source: [herringthorpe.com](http://herringthorpe.com/workspace/images/100_0866.JPG))</sub>

I have so far got the motors running in 1 direction by shorting pins 1,2 and 3,4 it also runs with shorting pins 1,4 or providing 5V to pin 4.

I have been testing by providing 12V to pins 5 and 7. I assume that I should be able to control the movement precisely / reverse / break as the motor is a BLDC servo.

Any help is very much appreciated, I can provide any readings using my multimeter if that will help. I am a bit of a novice when it comes to electronics!

Comment: As an aside, does anyone know what that style of heatsink on the top side of the board is called?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere near enough devices on that board for it to be anything like a servo controller.

I would guess you have a simple electronic commutator, with no provisions for any other control (except perhaps PWM speed control). I wouldn't be surprised if it couldn't even reverse.

The board looks to be just two layer, and all the parts are nice and big, so it shouldn't be too much trouble to map out the traces. That should get you a rough schematic.